# Set a default value for a dropdownlist from a list coming from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have this web page which shows the property of an object so that I may edit it, and I populate a `DropDownList`with strings coming from another class.

Here's the method I use to populate the `DropDownList`:

```
private void PopulateOBJSetDropdownList(object selectedobj = null)
        {
            List<string> listOBJSetName = m_OBJSetManager.GetListOBJSets().OrderBy(x => x.m_Name)
                                                           .Select(x => x.m_Name.ToString())
                                                           .Distinct()
                                                           .ToList();
            ViewBag.objSetID = new SelectList(listOBJSetName );
        }
```

The `ViewBag`property does its job quite well, but the list comes empty when editing the item.

I'm pretty sure it is because of this line:

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_OBJSetID, "Obj Set")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("objSetID ", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_OBJSetID)
        </div>
```

Because the dropdownlist is populated with `String.Empty`. This comes from a controller of objs.

Basically, I want this `DropDownList` to show me all the names of the objSets available, but I would also want it to have the correct objSet selected by default when editing an obj.

Does anyone can help? Am I clear enough? Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would avoid the viewbag. you might want to create a view model, and pass that instead.
but this can be done with the viewbag as well.

first, on your view, i would change your dropdown to the following

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.m_OBJSetID, DDLSelectitemListGoesHere)
```

if you do a view model, you can contain everything this page needs to use in one class, and send it to the view

```
public class MyViewModel{
    public List<YourModel> theModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DDLItems { get; set; }
}
```

then on your view, at the top

```
@model PROJECTNAME.NAMESPACE.MyViewModel
```

and you can fill in the drop down like so

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.theModel.m_OBJSetID, model.DDLItems)
```

hopefully one of those will get you through

Comment: Well I am already building a new view when I actually get into the Edit mode of the obj. My controller has this function which allows me to populate the drop down list, as mentioned before. So I don't understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I understand what you are suggesting. But won't building another view kind of compromise the first view I am already passing?

Comment: not a view, a ViewModel. its just a container to pass to your view that has all the data you need on that view.

Controller Action creates MyViewModel
return View(myVM);

the View then consumes that object for use

i think its a little more clean that passing an object and using ViewBag. Where I work we frown on ViewBag. I am still new here, so I don't understand why yet, but I like the VIewModels, so i am not complaining.

Comment: Oh nice! That sounds useful. Do you know where I could get information on this?

Comment: here is an explanation on ViewBag vs ViewModel ---- http://build.mt.gov/2011/12/14/when%20to%20use%20viewmodel,%20viewbag,%20viewdata,%20or%20tempdata.aspx

Comment: I will try my hand with the DropDownListFor and the ViewModel. Thank you. And I will devour this blog too!