# How to load list for DropdownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a registration page that requires State and Country selections. The items that populate these dropdowns come from an external database.

How do I make the call to populate those lists before the page renders?

```
public class RegisterModel
{
...
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States {get;set;}
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries {get;set;}
...
}

//Register.cshtml
@model Adw.Web.Models.RegisterModel

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.State)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.State, new SelectList(Model.States))

//Controller
public ActionResult Register()
    {
        .....
        RegisterModel rm = new RegisterModel();

        //The factories return List<string> 
        rm.States = new SelectList(stateFactory.Create(states.Payload));
        rm.Countries = new SelectList(countryFactory.Create(country.Payload));

        return View(rm);
    }
```

With the above setup I receive :

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'State'.

Summary - I need to make a web service call to get data for 2 dropdowns before the page renders.

Comment: i answered something like this recently, maybe the info in there will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714923/set-a-default-value-for-a-dropdownlist-from-a-list-coming-from-another-controlle/14715206#14715206

Comment: I tried to set it up as suggested in your link, but still can't seem to get it to work. I have updated my post reflect the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    ...
    public IList<string> States { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Countries { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Controller:

```
RegisterModel rm = new RegisterModel();

// read data from the database and add to the list
rm.States = new List<string> { "NY", "LA" };
rm.Countries = new List<string> { "USA", "Canada" };
```

The View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Countries)
@Html.DropDownListFor( x=>x.Countries, new SelectList(Model.Countries))

@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.States)
@Html.DropDownListFor( x=>x.States, new SelectList(Model.States))
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Ok Great! Thank you so much, I don't know why this seemed so hard for me. Here's a follow up though, Once my user is ready to submit the form how do I retrieve the selected values? I do have two other string properties called State and Country that I was trying to fill but perhaps i don't need too?

Comment: To @Zholen. You can use `FormCollection collection` in the methods parameter. See the following link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007068/mvc-4-how-to-get-the-selected-item-from-a-dropdown-list).